# Postgresql: Append object to a list

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, append, jsonb

I have data that has a key as string and value is a list of json, looks like

```
ID|data
A1|{key1:[{k1:v1,k2:v2},{{k3:v3,k4:v4}]}
```

I want to append json, say, `{k9:v9,k7:v6}` to this list for the `key1`, something like-

```
ID|data
A1|{key1:[{k1:v1,k2:v2},{{k3:v3,k4:v4},{k9:v9,k7:v6}]}
```

I have tried jsonb_set and other functions but they were of no use, example-

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET data = jsonb_set(data,'{key1,1}','{k9:v9,k7:v6}'::jsonb) where ID = 'A1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_insert()` function in order to append that part, after fixing the format of `JSONB` value ( otherwise you'd get "*ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json*" ) :

```
UPDATE tbl_name
   SET data = jsonb_insert(data,'{key1,1}','{"k9":"v9","k7":"v6"}'::jsonb) 
 WHERE ID = 'A1'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a275294a5a859340993235568ca52c8d)</kbd>